# How to pass value from one application to another application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an application in angular on click of a button it opens a popup(another application) in iFrame and sends data fill the fields to the popup(another application).I have webapi in c# from the popup application. How to load the values from source to destination application.

I tried to create a httpPost from the destiny(popup) application and inside the HttpPost redirect to HttpGet Method. Not sure will that work. I want an idea how to load the popup application with the input from the source application

Comment: In my opinion, When the you click the button in source application, use  httpclient to send a request with the data you want to show, Then in another application receive this request and pass data to the frontend.

Comment: How can the angular UI in the destination(angular) can read a request coming from source application(angular)